# dotnet build under Linux

Tags: c#, .net

Here is what i have:

[image]

When i do `dotnet build WorldServer.sln`

```
I receive the following error:

Microsoft (R) Build Engine version 15.7.177.53362 for .NET Core
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

  Nothing to do. None of the projects specified contain packages to restore.
/usr/share/dotnet/sdk/2.1.200/Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets(1179,5): error MSB3644: The reference assemblies for framework ".NETFramework,Version=v4.6.1" were not found. To resolve this, install the SDK or Targeting Pack for this framework version or retarget your application to a version of the framework for which you have the SDK or Targeting Pack installed. Note that assemblies will be resolved from the Global Assembly Cache (GAC) and will be used in place of reference assemblies. Therefore your assembly may not be correctly targeted for the framework you intend. [/home/venelin/wawsource/mmorpg/GameServer/WorldServer/WorldServer.csproj]

Build FAILED.

/usr/share/dotnet/sdk/2.1.200/Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets(1179,5): error MSB3644: The reference assemblies for framework ".NETFramework,Version=v4.6.1" were not found. To resolve this, install the SDK or Targeting Pack for this framework version or retarget your application to a version of the framework for which you have the SDK or Targeting Pack installed. Note that assemblies will be resolved from the Global Assembly Cache (GAC) and will be used in place of reference assemblies. Therefore your assembly may not be correctly targeted for the framework you intend. [/home/venelin/wawsource/mmorpg/GameServer/WorldServer/WorldServer.csproj]
    0 Warning(s)
    1 Error(s)

Time Elapsed 00:00:00.38
```

Is it even possible to build a Windows console application project under Linux. Is it going to build an exe under linux or it will be a program file that i can run under linux without any emulators ?

If it is possible what should i do? How can i fix this error ?

Comment: Your project is targetting the wrong framework...

Comment: What do you mean by that ? How can i target the correct one ?

Comment: Open your project file and change the target framework element.

Comment: I changed it to 4.5 and now i receive that `".NETFramework,Version=v4.5" were not found.` To which version i should change that ?

Comment: You cannot use full framework on Linux, you need to use .NET Core.

Comment: What should i specify to use net core ?

Comment: Maybe have a search on Google?

Comment: `netcoreapp2.0` is not working for me as i receive `/usr/share/dotnet/sdk/2.1.200/Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets(83,5): error MSB4184: The expression "[Microsoft.Build.Utilities.ToolLocationHelper]::GetPathToStandardLibraries(.NETFramework, netcoreapp2.0, '', AnyCPU, '')" cannot be evaluated. Input string was not in a correct format. [/home/venelin/wawsource/mmorpg/GameServer/WorldServer/WorldServer.csproj]` as an error

Comment: That means you have a bug in your code though.

Comment: It is compiling good and well on Windows.

Answer (score 0):

Given that you got this project from somewhere else and it is not coded by you from scratch, short answer - **you cannot build this or run on Linux**. It is not supposed to be the way.

The only possible way is to build and run on Windows with .NET 4.6.1 as described in the error message.

.NET Core is not a proper runtime to run your app.

**EDIT:** if it is coded by you, then follow this [official instruction how to port your code to .NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/porting/)

Comment: The whole code is created by me but i am running that on Windows. I am wondering can i run that console app on linux as well

Comment: What about monodevelop?

Comment: So you want to switch to Linux completely? Look at JetBrains Rider